# points where $f'(z)$ exists

Tags: complex-analysis

I am revising complex analysis from scratch, please just tell am I right?[image]

$f(z)=u_{xy}+iv_{xy}$, so by cauchy riemann I just need to solve the equation $u_x=v_y$ and $v_x=-u_y$ and those solutions are the points where $f'(z)$ exists. please confirm me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't just need the CR equations to hold, you need the partials to be continuous there! Here is question a. worked out:

$u(x,y)=yx$, $v(x,y)=y^2$. Thus,
$$\partial_xu=y\\
\partial_yu=x\\
\partial_xv=0\\
\partial_yv=2y
$$
The partials are continuous everywhere. The Cauchy Riemann equations give:
$$\partial_xu=\partial_yv\Leftrightarrow y=2y\Leftrightarrow y=0
\\
\partial_yu=-\partial_xv\Leftrightarrow x=0
$$
$f$ is only complex differentiable at $(x,y)=0$ and $f^{\prime}(z)=0$

For b:
$u(x,y)=x^2$, $v(x,y)=y^2$. Thus,
$$\partial_xu=2x\\
\partial_yu=0\\
\partial_xv=0\\
\partial_yv=2y
$$
The partials are continuous everywhere. The Cauchy Riemann equations give:
$$\partial_xu=\partial_yv\Leftrightarrow 2x=2y\Leftrightarrow x=y
\\
\partial_yu=-\partial_xv\Leftrightarrow 0=0
$$
$f$ is only complex differentiable at $S=\left\{(x,x)\in \mathbb{C}:x\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$

Comment: cheers!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!